# How to center smaller text with bigger css

Tags: html, css

How to center smaller text with bigger CSS?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar"> 
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" style="">
        <font color="white">LOGO</font> 
            <div class="menuleft">          
                <a href="home">HOME </a>
                <a href="images">PORTOFOLIO </a>
                <a href="link1">LINK1 </a>
                <a href="link2">LINK2 </a>
                <a href="link3">LINK3 </a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sGtcE/11/

Comment: what is the problem or what is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to centre the text vertically you cannot use `vertical-align`. Since the `.menuleft` (child) div is sitting inside the `.navbar` (parent) div, I set the parent to a `position: relative;`, and then put the following code for the child:

```
.menuleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

To explain, the `position: absolute;` is a requirement to use `top: 50%;` positioning, which means that the child will be positioned 50% of its own width from the top of the parent div. The `transform: translateY(-50%);` changes the position of the child on the Y-axis by -50% of the parent div, making the child vertically centred inside the parent on the y-axis. The `right: 0;` is just a replacement for `float: right;` as you cannot use float with an absolutely positioned element.

### [Here is an updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sGtcE/13/)

---

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome for me @ZxAndrew - what's happening for you?

Comment: it's because font-size

Comment: i coppied the jsfiddle and now it's working ok, thank you ^^

Comment: absolute might not be needed http://jsfiddle.net/sGtcE/14/ , this way, menu and logo do not overlapp if window is smaller .... absolute is to be used as less as possible and should be forgotten by beginners untill they know how flux and positionning is cared of :)